# Whats the equivalent of TAB +TAB in Visual Studio Code VSCode

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to automatically create a `foreach` (or other) structure.

Does VSCode have something similar?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, VSCode does support [snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets). They appear in the completion list, and you can insert them by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or just <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Alternatively, you can use the `Insert Snippet` command found in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics#_command-palette).

[image]

The snippet shown in the `.gif` above is provided by the [C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp).

Comment: Thanks, that helped.